# How get list of web browsers in system

Tags: java, android

How can I get programmatically a list of web-browsers in system?

Update:
I know what manifestfile of that applications must have attribute `android:scheme="http"` or `android:scheme="https"`. I know how get list of all application in system throw `getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages( 0);`. I don't know how get this attribute?

Comment: have you try something?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I guess you just have to test if the package exists. There is probably no way to list "browsers".

Comment: I know what manifestfile of that applications must have attribute `android:scheme="http"` or `android:scheme="https"`. I know how get list of all application in system throw `getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages( 0);`. I don't know how get this attribute?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can check, for example, what `Activities` in the system can handle a specific `Intent`, like this:

```
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
                String name = info.name;
            }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: he's just asking the system which apps installed on it will open the `Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")`, very clever way of querying for browsers if you ask me.

Comment: `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` or `0` (another answer) only returned 1 app, which was my app itself which also handles HTTP.  I changed the flag to `MATCH_ALL` and then it returned all the web browsers. 
Android 8.0, emulator.

Comment: How can I remove a specific browser from the list (eg., Chrome), and show list of rest of browsers to choose from?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a package manager along with an intent to open a browser to get the list of all the browsers in the device. To get the package name of the app, you can use `it.activityInfo.packageName`, where `it` is a list item.

```
val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.aurl.com"))
val browsersList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(browserIntent, 
                   PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)
browsersList.forEach {
    val packageName = it.activityInfo.packageName
}
```