# How to create an intent that will view a local HTML file on all devices

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I really don't understand how this can be so difficult but I see it being asked for the last 4 years, and the same problems/errors are always reported by the OP.  I have tried the various solutions given but none work on all devices.  My current code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(htmlFile);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

This works on my Motorola Photon, my Samsung Galaxy 10.1 Tab and my HTC Droid DNA.  But does not work on a Note 3 or a GS4.  Both of those devices crash, most likely with the ActivityNotFoundException based on what others have reported (I don't have the devices in hand and the users reporting this do not have debuggers).

I also see many apps in the play store that are just for the purpose of reading local HTML files.  So seemingly there is something needed to create the association and allow local HTML files (in the Downloads directory in my particular case) to be viewed by the browser.  Does anybody have a solution that will work on all platforms?

Comment: You can omit the setClassName, I think this is the reason of ActivityNotFoundException in some devices.

Comment: Actually, I originally did not have that but then I get ActivityNotFoundException on my devices :)  I suppose as a hack I could try the one way and if that throws then try the other way, but I would have hoped there would be a single solution for all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "text/html"); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

It's more generic as you don't need to define the browser package name.
This will open a prompt to user to choose with which browser he wants to open the url.
**However it will not save you from `ActivityNotFoundException` as you never know if the user have software to handle html files installed on the device or not.**

Comment: Thanks for replying EvZ... that doesn't crash at least but it also doesn't seem to really be connected to the browsers, per se.  For example, on my Droid DNA I have the default Android browser as well as Chrome installed yet neither appear in the selection list.  I get "HTMLViewer" and "ES Note Editor" as my only choices, but no actual browsers.  HTMLViewer kinda works, but the UI is terrible...

Comment: I should note that on my Photon (Android 2.3.4) "Browser" is one of the choices (in addition to HTMLViewer and ES Note Editor)... but on my newer devices (4.0.4 and 4.2.2) no browsers are listed.  If I could get the full list including browsers on the newer devices this would be perfect.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can try to get a list of installed Web Browsers as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15113063/1970317 and than send intent according to the package name of installed browser. It's more complicated but it's an option as well.

Comment: Thanks for that idea.  I'll report back with what I eventually come up with.

Comment: Good luck and don't forget to share with us!