# queryIntentActivities returns zero on AVD while correct browser count on a real device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have following code taken from [How get list of web browsers in system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112885/how-get-list-of-web-browsers-in-system) supposed to return all browsers installed on a device.

This does not raise any error but `browsersList` size is zero on any AVD while works as expected on a real smart phone.

What am I missing?

### Edit

*Tested AVDs*

```
Android 11 - DOESN'T WORK

Android 10 - Works
```

*Tested Actual Devices*

```
Android 10 - Works

Android 9 - Works

Android 8 - Works
```

Since I don't have an actual device with Android 11 not sure if the v11 is the problem. But it seems so.

```
val packageManager: PackageManager = this.getPackageManager()
val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.aurl.com"))
val browsersList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
    browserIntent,
    PackageManager.MATCH_ALL
)
browsersList.forEach {
    val packageName = it.activityInfo.packageName
}
```

Comment: Which android version do you have on the device and the emulator?

Comment: @sdex sorry my bad. should've added before. edited my question and added the versions I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are new changes in android 11 in package visibility. 
More info you can find in documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility